# JAXB. How to annotate classes to get following XML?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have xml file and I want to create set of classes based on it with JAXB annotations, which will be used to un-marshall XML files.

XML:

```
<widgetOutput>
<dataItems>
<dataItem><isLimit>false</isLimit></dataItem>
<dataItem><size>1000</size></dataItem>
<dataItem><key>Canada</key><value>1</value></dataItem>
<dataItem><key>US</key><value>2</value></dataItem>
<dataItem><key>Italy</key><value>3</value></dataItem>
<dataItem><key>France</key><value>4</value></dataItem>
...
<dataItem><key>some_N_key_here</key><value>some_N_value_here</value></dataItem>
<status>complete</status>
</dataItems>
</widgetOutput>
```

I can't modify this xml, it is being generated byt he web service. 
Please advise how classes along with annotations may look like.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the trick here is that nodes <dataItem> have different nature: some of them are used to represent key-value pairs and others contain 'metadata'. I have generated java files, but they are not good... DataItem class coonatins only one field: isLimit. I guess this is because xsd is not good...

Comment: Alright I was able to generate java classes. DataItem class which was generated contains consolidated fields: isLimit, size, key, value. What is actually is not exactly what I was looking for. I wanted to have isLimit and size as fileds of WidgetOutput class. But seems it is not possible to achieve... it doesn't make sense to have such cumbersome objects.

Comment: It's hard to tell here if you still have a question or if your question has been answered. Seems like the question regarding how to generate Java classes with JAXB annotation is answered. If you have a further question, I suggest you post that specific question as a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a schema for the expected XML and using XJC to create the Java classes for you.

Comment: Is it something I can quickly do in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes. Eclipse has a tool for creating a schema. XJC is a command line tool that comes with the JDK.

Comment: Thx, I have generated classes. Have added some extra comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use tools such as the ones provided by NetBeans to create all necessary classes from a WSDL file.

Or use a Maven plugin if you're using Maven.

Comment: I do not have a wsdl file, this is the file generated by the RESTful web service